# How can I get linear time complexity from this code?

Tags: python-2.7, list, iteration

The rest of this code is meant to search through any number of drives on our data analysis workstations and check that a particular file is not missing. This is of course just a piece of that code. DriveFind() is calling a function that returns a list of letters that passed as True: os.path.isdir(drives)==True.  It then iterates through those drives and searches through each set folder in each drive.  It doesn't seem to me that I can get linear search time from this process since it has to enter each drive and from there iterate through the os.listdir() of each set folder. The function setFinder() returns a list of set folders in which a subsequent function searches for any missing files Anyway, here is the code:

```
def setFinder():
    for driveList in driveFind(): # iterates through list of drive letters
        try:os.chdir(driveList) # changes directory to each drive
        except WindowsError:pass
        print 'Drive being scanned:',driveList
        for setFolder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            # finds setFolders to send to next function
            if os.path.isdir(setFolder)==True:
```

Comment: The presence of two for loops here does not make it quadratic. You're still linear in files.

Comment: "linear search time" - when you say linear the question is related to what...

Comment: Well the Im referring to the nesting of the for loops

Comment: I guess what I want to know is whether there is a way for this to run faster.

Comment: Well... you seem to be searching every folder of every drive in the machine, so that could be fixed.

Comment: Yes its meant to do just that, except for the C: drive of course.

Comment: How could I have this code scan two drives at the same time?